# Android Studio - Não aparece acentuação

Tags: android, linux, android-studio

Olá, estou com um erro muito estranho no Android Studio, de repente ele parou de aceitar as acentuações nas string e comentários, quando tento digitar por exemplo "ã" ele mostra somente "a". Já tentei tudo no File Encoding e nada. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigado.

[image: Print do File Encondings]

Comment: Você teve mais sorte que eu, que nunca vi acentos no código (nem nos comentários). Pra ver acentos, defino strings em /res/values/strings.xml. e as uso no lugar de hardcode strings no código. Acredito que seja estratégia do software para evitar comportamentos estranhos, mas é só um palpite.

Comment: O problema não está aí, a IDE não está aceitando acentos nem no strings.xml

Comment: Ah, entendi. Tente assim: escreva o texto no notepad, copie e cole. Veja se o app compila e aceita os acentos, Eu sei... não é uma solução, mas um quebra galho. Pelo menos vc não fica sem acento.

Comment: Sim, ele compila. Tem trechos de código no projeto já com acentos, antes de acontecer esse erro, o app roda normal.

Comment: já tentou reiniciar a ide? as vezes ela dá uns bugs bizarros. aqui comigo acontece com certa frequencia um que a ide simplesmente "esquece" que eu digitei código novo e insiste em compilar a versão "velha".

Comment: Já, atualizei e reiniciei.

Comment: No pior dos casos é só reinstalar a IDE, as vezes é mais rápido do que achar a solução, claro, saber qual era o problema é sempre bom.

Comment: Instalei em outro computador e os acentos funcionaram bem. Suspeito que seja algum plugin. Você instalou algum recentemente?

Answer (score 5):

Resolvi o problema aplicando essa solução "**Frozen keyboard input - "iBus" problems on Linux**" descrita em: https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues.html

A princípio ele diz que há uma interação entre o daemon iBUS e o Android Studio e que em alguns casos a IDE pode parar de responder ao teclado ou inserir coisas aleatórias. Este bug já foi reportado para JetBrains e iBus.

No link informa que a solução para este problema e roda o código abaixo antes de rodar o Android Studio para forçar o iBus em modo síncrono.

```
$ IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1 ibus-daemon -xrd
```

Ou rodar este outro código para desabilitar o iBus para o Android Studio:

```
$ XMODIFIERS= ./bin/studio.sh
```

Emfim... Usei o primeiro e deu certo para mim. Já tinha tentado tudo, reinstalar o Android Studio, apagar todas as configurações (Incluindo criar um novo usuário, pois no root os inputs funcionavam). Já estava pensando em mudar de SO. Estou usando o Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki

Answer (score 2):

Talvez, no Ubuntu, para reaver a acentuação, seja necessário apenas executar o comando no terminal:
`ibus-daemon -drx`

Mas no elementary OS eu não tive a mesma sorte. Foi necessário fazer o seguinte:

Como resolvi o problema de acentuação do Android Studio no **elementary OS**.

Primeiramente, *isso é problema do elementary OS (ou do Linux que você estiver utilizando)* e não do Android Studio. Portanto, **não adianta reinstalar**, não vai resolver!

Resolvendo...

**No elementary OS**
Passo 1: Instale o "iBus QT4".
Em um terminal:
`sudo apt install ibus-qt4`

Passo 2: Abra o iBus
`ibus-setup`

Passo 3: Na segunda aba, "Método de Entrada", veja se tem a opção "Português - Português(Brasil)".

- 3.A) Se não tiver a entrada "**Português - Português(Brasil)**", clique no botão ao lado "**Adicionar**", procure "Português - Português(Brasil)" e adicione. Siga para o passo **3.B**;
- 3.B) Se tiver a entrada "**Português - Português(Brasil)**", exclua a entrada "English" e deixe somente a "Português". Feche o **iBus** e vá para o passo **4**;

Passo 4: Após fechar o iBus, no terminal digite:
`ibus-daemon -drx`

Agora faça um teste. Isso vai resolver o problema até a próxima reinicialização. Para manter funcionando "4éva", você precisa colocar o comando do **passo 4** na inicialização automática (no elementary OS).